# Inject a Hibernate Interceptor with Guice / GuicePersist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, guice, guice-servlet, guice-persist

I'm using JPA with [Guice Persist](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GuicePersist) for my GAE projects and [Restlet](https://restlet.com/) for the REST interface. Under the hood good old [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) delivers the JPA service.

[image]
[image]

This works like a charm, and Guice injects necessary JPA parts into my classes, for example an `EntityManager` in the `RestletServlet`;

[image]

Now i want to use a `SessionInterceptor` to insert create/edit timestamps and current active users to my entities. In old projects i used a static `HibernateUtil` class with ThreadLocal variables to store the sessions. In my new project i want to solve this with Guice. Guice needs to inject an `EntityManager` in my `SessionInterceptor` so i can load the current active user from the database.

The `SessionInterceptor` needs to be created in a Hibernate context and its not permitted to configure this after startup. Therefore i created a `SessionInterceptorFactory` which uses a Guice Injector. In `persistence.xml`

[image]

[image]

This works (yes its ugly), i have a `SessionInterceptor` with Guice Injection.

[image]

But when i try this code;

[image]

> [ERROR] 1) No implementation for javax.persistence.EntityManager was
>   bound. [ERROR]   while locating
>   com.google.inject.Provider [ERROR]
>   for the 1st parameter of
>   com.ludus.server.hibernate.SessionInterceptor.(SessionInterceptor.java:20)
>   [ERROR]   while locating com.ludus.server.hibernate.SessionInterceptor

I need to connect (`bound`) the JPA (Hibernate) configuration with the `SessionInterceptor` in Guice like i did with the `RestletServlet`, but how?

Who can help me with this Guice configuration?

Apart from this, the current `SessionInterceptorFactory` is a 'dirty Guice hack', is there a clean Guice solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a brand new (and empty) injector in your `SessionInterceptorFactory`, when what you want to do is to hook it into the main injector you have elsewhere.

This is a fairly common problem when attempting to integrate Guice into tools that pre-date dependency injection: If the config only gives you the option to provide a "factory class" rather than accepting an instance, then you have no choice but to pass the reference via a static variable. You can make this pretty robust by doing it with a thread-local, but it's not very satisfactory.

In the case of Hibernate however, you can tidy this up by using the API to build your `SessionFactory` rather than using the configuration file. You can call [`setInterceptor`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setInterceptor(org.hibernate.Interceptor)) method on the `Configuration` object which builds your `SessionFactory`. You haven't shown how you're creating this at the moment.

Comment: Hello Tim, with Guice Persist you use JpaPersistModule in the createInjector and specify the JPA/Hibernate configuration in persistence.xml (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA). I'll have to check how this is done with code...